# R code (ggplot) not outputting to .tex file

Tags: r, tikzdevice

I'm relatively new to this so possibly a duplicate question but I am trying to use library `tikzDevice` to add a ggplot figure to a LaTeX document as per this guidance: http://iltabiai.github.io/tips/latex/2015/09/15/latex-tikzdevice-r.html

This is my code:

```
tikz('Figure_1.tex', width = 3.5, height=3)
Figure_1 <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x=Year, y=Numbers2, fill=Level, label = Numbers2)) + 
geom_col()
print(plot)
device.off()
```

But then when I look at the `Figure_1.tex` document, all it says is

```
% Created by tikzDevice version 0.12 on 2018-07-23 15:28:19
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
```

And there is no code there. How can I ensure that the outputted `.tex` file contains the aforementioned figure but in vectorized format?

Answer (score 4):

Your code produces not only no usable output file, but also error messages. This should be a clear warning that something is wrong. Anyway, the following works:

```
library(tikzDevice)
library(ggplot2)
y <- exp(seq(1,10,.1))
x <- 1:length(y)
data <- data.frame(Year = x, Numbers2 = y, Level = 1)

tikz('Figure_1.tex', width = 3.5, height=3)
Figure_1 <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x=Year, y=Numbers2, fill=Level, label = Numbers2)) + 
  geom_col()
print(Figure_1) # you *have to* print the object you created
dev.off() # not device.off()
```